# Combine http to https and domain redirects using mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I'm trying to redirect `www.example.com` to a hosted blog at `https://www.example.wordpress.com`. The domain redirect works, but gives me a 403 error because it's redirecting http to https. Example.com is never going to be used beyond the redirect, I don't want to get an ssl cert for it.

There's similar questions (eg., [htaccess redirect to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)), but these all address one of the two parts of the problem (either `www.example1.com` to `www.example2.com`, or `http://domain1.com` to `http://domain1.com`).

Here's my current .htacess. How do I add something that actually takes care of the https issue without messing up the domain redirect?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.wordpress.com [R=301,L]
```

**Update:**
My working .htaccess file is this; apparently wordpress.com does the redirect to https itself (which I knew, but wasn't able to make work previously):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.curiouscitytc.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.curiouscommute.wordpress.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Have you tried redirecting to http? WordPress hosted websites redirect http to https.

Comment: My original .htaccess file was simply `RedirectPermanent / http://www.example.wordpress.com`; this gives a 403 error same as redirecting to https does.

Comment: @AWippler: That was my original thought, although apparently that does work if I use RedirectMatch instead of RedirectPermanent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ https://www.example.wordpress.com
```

Comment: This works ... with the exception that I'm redirecting to http instead of https; apparently wordpress does the redirect to https itself, which was my original plan. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't do what you're attempting to do. If the client is connecting to your server and expecting to talk HTTPS with you, you can't give it a non-HTTPS response. That's the point of "Secure" in HTTPS.

You can either use a self-signed cert, or there are plenty of low-cost (or even free) SSL certificate providers out there.

Comment: A browser redirect should be fine.

Comment: @Matt You have to establish a TLS session with the client to be able to issue the redirect. Otherwise it would be trivial for me to MitM your HTTPS traffic and issue a redirect to my insecure site. This is what TLS and HSTS prevents.

Comment: maybe we're talking cross purposes or the author hasn't explained it well.  The browser will establish an insecure or secure session to the original URL, read back 301 - permanent redirect, close the original session then create a new secure https session with www.example.wordpress.com.  Perhaps I've misunderstood what he's wanting to do.

Comment: I believe the OP has that working (on port 80, HTTP), but now wants the same behavior when the client attempts HTTPS/port 443 (ie, add a 301 for `https://www.example.com` => `https://www.example.wordpress.com`)

Comment: @fukawi2 - As far as I know (can you tell this isn't usually in my job description?) my origin domain doesn't have any kind of SSL certificate, since I haven't set that up with the host. Any kind of redirect I try to do returns a 403 error. I did find/try a variant on [this help page](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL) in the apache wki, but no go.

Comment: @Matt That's what I thought the process was, but there's clearly something I don't understand about https going on (well, many somethings, this is very much not my area of expertise).

Comment: That wiki article is redirecting HTTP to HTTPS; is that what is not working for you?